# why mysql row_count is always -1 after update?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, rowcount

I execute an update statement which affects 1 row. Then I write select row_count() and the result is always -1.

I checked out [row_count](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//information-functions.html#function_row-count) in mysql but I dont understand what I have to config in my mysql to make row_count() on.

Anybody can help me?

Also the same thing when I use insert like this.

INSERT INTO tb_fr_itemsderendicionfondorotatorio (VERSION,estado,ejercicio,importe,tema,oidObjeto,tipoObjeto,codigoObjeto,oid_Ren‌​dicionFondoRotatorio,oid_AnulacionRendicionFondoRotatorio,fecha) VALUES (0,1,0,3000,'mt',18679,'AnticipoRendicion','2013000005',4979,NULL,'2013-05-25');

SELECT ROW_COUNT();

I m making test from SQLYog interface and always return -1. In server Im using hibernate with java.

Comment: Are you doing any selects on that connection between the time of the update and the `row_count()` call?

Comment: Which version of MySQL is in use?

Comment: no, I m not doing any selects between. My version is 5.5.32

Comment: the same occurs when I make an insert

Answer (score 1):

The most reasonable explanation is that your "`SELECT ROW_COUNT()`" query is not being immediately preceded, on the same database connection, by an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement.

This function has meaning only within the same database session. If the query is being run from a different connection, we'd expect it to return a -1.  If there is some other statement being executed   (for example, a COMMIT statement) then we'd expect it to return a -1.

Are you running this from the mysql command line? Or some other interface? (If it's another interface, I suspect it may be executing a COMMIT or is churning connections.)

---

**Follow-up:**

I suggest you try this same test case using the mysql command line client, and see what results you get with that. Also, you could do the same thing from a Java application, and see what you get there.

I suspect that this is an issue specific to SQLyog, rather than an issue with MySQL itself. But some test cases from another client would help confirm that.

I've run a test, using SQLYog GUI v10.2, and MySQL version '5.1.46-community', and ROW_COUNT() is returning expected values.

Comment: I m running from the sqlyog interface. perhaps autocommit is enabled. Im going to check it

Comment: I m running from the sqlyog interface. I open a new connection, and I write                                                         INSERT INTO tb_fr_itemsderendicionfondorotatorio (VERSION,estado,ejercicio,importe,tema,oidObjeto,tipoObjeto,codigoObjeto,oid_RendicionFondoRotatorio,oid_AnulacionRendicionFondoRotatorio,fecha)
VALUES (0,1,0,3000,'mt',18679,'AnticipoRendicion','2013000005',4979,NULL,'2013-05-25');

SELECT ROW_COUNT();
Also I probe with an update, and always return -1